# execution of ssh in python script which is called from php exec command

Tags: php, python, ssh, remote-server

I have a PHP code which calls a python script.In python script i am connecting to a remote system using ssh and running a command.When python code is executed independently all seems perfect,but when i call it from php, the connection can't be established and it prints an empty string as output in the browser.

Here is my php script

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('python p.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Python script(p.py) is as follows

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["ssh remotehost uptime"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print "program output:", out
```

When I execute

> python p.py

the program successfully prints the result.And when the php script is executed the browser just displays

> program output:

which shows python script gets executed and the problem is in ssh connection when called through php.
can anyone suggest me a way to make it work properly?

EDIT:

when my python code has database connections ,similar issues araised .
After surfing i found that in /etc/sysconfig I have to give

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1

Is there any similar issues that should be considered for connections over ssh??

Answer (score -1):

Try using this code in your php code. Note : the file should have a .php extension.

```
 <html>  
 <head></head>  
 <body>  
 <H3>Executing...</H3>  
 <?php exec("p.py"); ?>  
 <H3>Completed...</H3>  
 </body>  
 </html>
```

Comment: :When i use exec too the same issue araises,the browser just prints executing and completed without printing the results of the command given through php.I have tested with storing the output of exec to a variable and printing it too.it didnt work